# cross site sharing UI without iframe

Tags: asp.net, seo, cross-domain, cross-site

we host catalog data and UI for our clients. we do not build entire web site for them. so for the time being client puts an iframe and points URL to our hosting site. it was working fine but now just because of iframe they are lossing SEO.
so my question is how to achieve my goal without iframe.

1) how can i embed/inject/merge UI hosted by US to our client web site.
2) Get SEO benefits

i Hope my question is pretty clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use proxy on your domain and pass through the request, explain here: http://www.johnchapman.name/aspnet-proxy-page-cross-domain-requests-from-ajax-and-javascript/
does not have to be ajax, just inject the content at the server, you get the idea I hope

Comment: Thanks K..but what about all the postback event? how do i handle those.

Comment: oh, well that is complex now, consider exposing some API for them to easily consume and submit updates to your server, sorry no easy solution